# TFS build throwing error of missing reference of GAC assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have created build script for my project. Project refer to the dotnetCHARTING DLL from GAC.
After initiating the Build on TFS am getting error's related to dotnetCHARTING.
Is there any way I can configure the GAC DLL reference in build script?

Thanks,
Chetan